# How to deserialize a nested dictionary?

Tags: c#, json, dictionary, deserialization

I am writing a Windows Phone app that will get a set of data from a server and display each entry in a list box.

The data comes from the server looking like this

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "value1": 777103069782066, 
      "value2": "SomeString", 
      "value3": "TextToDisplay1"
    }, 
    {
      "value1": 750050696652932, 
      "value2": "SomeString2", 
      "value3": "TextToDisplay2"
    }, 
    {
      "value1": 516092242936133, 
      "value2": "SomeString3", 
      "value3": "TextToDisplay3"
    } 
  ]
}
```

Then I deserialize the data like this

```
Dictionary<string, object> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, object>>(json);
```

The problem is that all my values get mashed into one dictionary entry

Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks,
Chris

Comment: Your JSON consists of an object with an array of dictionaries. If you're deserializing the entire JSON string I suspect you're getting a dictionary with only one entry with the key `"data"`. Since there are multiple nested dictionaries, do you want to obtain all of them or just one?

Answer (score 0):

`Dictionary<string,object>` are supposed to have a unique key per value, in your example, all the items have the same keys (value1,value2,value3). That's why all your values get mashed into one dictionary entry.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you are unintentionally making a dictionary containing one object by the key "data" containing a single object, which is a list of dictionaries?